# jQuery select first image src in container with image filename extension

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This current code doesn't work.

`$loaded_data.find('img').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)/i).first().attr('src')`

It will allow `img` with the ext of `.php?image=qweqweqwe2qe2ad` etc.

Comment: *It will allow img with the ext of `.php?image=qweqweqwe2qe2ad` etc.* What do you mean?

Comment: Some images in my loaded content have the src value of `loadimage.php?id=123123` I don't want to select those images I only want `img` with the `src` of .jpg etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `match` method in jQuery API so chain in your code will throw error.

jQuery filter() method can help

```
var $image_first= $loaded_data.find('img').filter(function(){  
      return $(this).attr('src').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i)
}).first();

 $image_first.doSomething()
```

Comment: How would I re-write this with my data container... E.g. as above?

Would I just write `$loaded_data.find('img').filter(...`

Comment: The code I used was this, but it doesn't seem to run. Sorry If I'm being incompetent.. `$loaded_data.find('img').filter(function(){  
      var $image_first = $(this).attr('src').match(/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i)
    }).first()`

Comment: put some sample html into jsfiddle.net

Comment: you have used `filter` incorrectly. Must return the match as I've shown. What it does is build a jQuery object of images that pass that test

Answer (score 1):

Add "$" to the end of your expression to make sure the string ends with dot + one of your allowed extensions.

```
/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/i
```

Comment: Now the script doesn't run at all :(